# Regular expression url pattern matching for the end of the string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match wikipedia entry page only, which includes:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_mechanics
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple

But excludes:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Community_portal
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:About

Basically I want to weed out the ones that has a colon in the last part.
This will match both of the cases:

`const regex = /https?:\/\/.*wikipedia.org\/wiki\/\w*/`

I thought if I put `$` in the end it will match the first case only, because it matches cases where it ends with words only:

`const regex = /https?:\/\/.*wikipedia.org\/wiki\/\w*$/`

But this won't match any of them. Can anyone help explain why?

Comment: Ohh yes! It was the flags, I was testing on a multiline string. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have have the global and multiline flags `/gm` set to ensure that `$` matches at the end of each line and not just the entire string (and that you get multiple matches)

```
/https?:\/\/.*wikipedia.org\/wiki\/\w*$/gm
```